# Form a single list from multiple answers in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I currently have this piece of code in Prolog

```
s1(Q,100) :- generate(Q).

generate([X,Y,S,P]) :-
  nat(X, 49),
  nat(Y, 98),
  S is X+Y,
  P is X*Y,
  S =< 100,
  X < Y.

nat(2,_).
nat(X,N) :-
  N > 2,
  M is N - 1,
  nat(Y,M),
  X is Y + 1.
```

It currently generates a list of quadruples, `X, Y, S, P` such that

- 1 < X < 49
- 1 < Y < 98
- 1 < X < Y
- X + Y <= 100
- P = X * Y
- S = X + Y

This works and creates all possible solutions but with multiple answers (i.e,  having to press `;` every time to get the next result.)

How can a single list be formed of all these results, for instance,

```
[[2, 3, 5, 6], [2, 4, 6, 8], ...]
```

*without* using any built in predicates such as `findall/3`?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `member` or `memberchk`? Those are built in predicates well. There seems to be an epidemic phobia of common ISO Prolog predicates in SO Prolog questions for some odd reason. ;)

Comment: @lurker Yeah, not allowed to use them, anything built in. In sense have to code from scratch in pure Prolog.

Comment: As a hint to one approach: write yourself a simple `memberchk/2` predicate (you can look that one up), then write a simple recursive `genall/1` that starts with an empty list and fills it recursively, but avoids elements that were already added (that's where `memberchk/2` comes in).

Answer (score 2):

First, the upper interval bounds you gave for `X` and `Y` are both off by one:

- `1 < X < 49` does not match `nat(X,49)`, `1 < X =< 49` does.
- `1 < Y < 98` does not match `nat(Y,98)`, `1 < Y =< 98` does.

Let's get it started!

If you want to collect all solutions *without* using `findall/3` (etc), one way is to calculate the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) (a.k.a. cross-product) of two lists `Xs` and `Ys`.

To get `Xs` and `Ys`, we can use the builtin predicate [`numlist/3`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=numlist/3):

```
?- numlist(2,49,Xs).
Xs = [2,3,4,/* consecutive integers from 5 to 47 omitted */,48,49].

?- numlist(2,98,Ys).
Ys = [2,3,4,/* consecutive integers from 5 to 96 omitted */,97,98].
```

To combine every `X` in `Xs` with every `Y` in `Ys` we use [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)   [`xproduct//3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30328630/4609915).

For selecting which quadruples to collect, use the grammar rule `x_y_maybe_quadruple//2`:

```
x_y_maybe_quadruple(X,Y) -->
   (  { 1 < X, X < Y, X+Y =< 100 }       % if all these conditions are met
   -> { P is X * Y },
      { S is X + Y },
      [[X,Y,S,P]]                        % then add single "quadruple"
   ;  []                                 % else add nothing.
   ).
```

Let's put it all together!

```
?- numlist(2,49,Xs),
   numlist(2,98,Ys),
   phrase(xproduct(x_y_maybe_quadruple,Xs,Ys),Qss).
Qss = [[2,3,5,6],[2,4,6,8],
       /* lots of other quadruples omitted */,
       [48,51,99,2448],[48,52,100,2496]].
```

So... do we actually get *all* quadruples we would have gotten if we had used `findall/3`?

```
?- findall(Qs,generate(Qs),Qss1),
   numlist(2,49,Xs),
   numlist(2,98,Ys),
   phrase(xproduct(x_y_maybe_quadruple,Xs,Ys),Qss2),
   Qss1 = Qss2.
Qss1 = Qss2, 
Qss2 = [[2, 3, 5, 6], [2, 4, 6, 8], [2|...], [...|...]|...],
Xs   = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10|...],
Ys   = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10|...].
```

**It works!** And not just that: we get *exactly the same* quadruples in the *exact same order*!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a solution to a list if it is not already in the list..if its in the list fail.

so

```
myfindall(List) :-
   my_find(List,[]),
   !.

my_find(List,Ac) :-
   s1(Q,100), 
   my_set(Q,Ac,NewAc),
   my_find(List,NewAc).
my_find(Ac,Ac).

my_set(X,[],[X]) :-
   !.
my_set(H,[H|_],_) :-
   !,
   fail.
my_set(X,[H|T],L) :- 
   my_set(X,T,Rtn),
   L = [H|Rtn].
```